# Google Translate get synonyms and examples

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

Can I access word's synonyms and examples along with the translation itself, when using Google Translate API?

I checked out [docs](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started) but I don't see anything like that.

Comment: Have you found any solution since then? I tried to load Google Translate page  manually with the intention to parse it. But unfortunately I could't even load it. Here where I finished: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274481/get-no-response-when-sending-manually-request-to-google-translate

Comment: @János no solution for now, tried to load page too but it's very unnatural so I better wait when google improve their API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot get the synonyms and examples along with the translated text.As currently they have only 3 methods in the Translate API.The 3 methods are detections.list, languages.list and translations.list. So i think it would be great if you make a feature request for this API at [PIT](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/) of AppEngine.

Comment: Done https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11773&thanks=11773&ts=1426115997

Comment: I have up voted feature request too, I need synonym also, have you found any alternative since then?

Answer (score 0):

Pearson released their free API which includes examples, part of speech, and synonyms. Check it out: http://developer.pearson.com/apis/dictionaries

`http://api.pearson.com/v2/dictionaries/lase%20/entries?headword=hola`

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "offset": 0,
  "limit": 10,
  "count": 1,
  "total": 1,
  "url": "/v2/dictionaries/lase /entries?headword=hola",
  "results": [
    {
      "datasets": [
        "lase",
        "dictionary"
      ],
      "headword": "hola",
      "id": "ct59rx0q97",
      "part_of_speech": "interjection",
      "senses": [
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Pearson is going to suspend their API : http://developer.pearson.com/apis/dictionaries

Comment: @ThilawFabrice why?? No!! This is why it's hard to rely on these services. I ended up just downloading and slicing up my own dictionary. I'd love to get my hands on SpanishDict! dictionaries. They're extremely comprehensive.