# Is it a way to get synonyms / english definitions with Google Translate API?

Tags: google-translate

I need synonym info from Google Transle API. Is it possible to get it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28998578). Looks like they [opened a PIT](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11773&thanks=11773&ts=1426115997) to get the feature added. You should star it to add weight!